# Cannot find ACM Certificate to a custom domain in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-certificate-manager

So, I've been trying to add my own domain to AWS API Gateway, but cannot add an ACM certificate. Even though I was issued a certificate from the AWS Certificate Manager, I can’t select it from the **“Choose a certificate”** drop-down selector. It only says **“No certificates in eu-west-3 match the domain name you entered”**.

Within the AWS Certificate Manager, I see that the status is **”Issued”**. What am I doing wrong here? I must be missing something.

Information that might be useful:

- Domain was bought through Google
- The ARN of the certificate contains `arn:aws:acm:eu-west-3:…`. Also the url of both the API gateway and Certificate Manager console contains `eu-west-3`
- The domain I want to use in API Gateway was pasted from the certificate domain field to avoid any typos.
- For what is worth, the domain I want to use is actually a subdomain.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does the custom domain name for API Gateway match the certificate you created?

Comment: Yes. I even copied the domain name from the Certificates Manager list and pasted it as the custom domain to avoid typos

Comment: When issuing the ACM, did you also enter subdomain in the list? Also, its really helpful to issue wild card ACM for domain. eg - 

1. main domain - mydomain.com

2. sub domain - my.subdomain.com

3. wild card - *.mydomain.com 

With wild card you can map it to any sub domain

Comment: I issued the ACM specifically for my target subdomain (e.g., api.example.com). I didn´t know that a wild card was better... Does that affect the TLS certificate I already mapped to the root domain?

Comment: The wild card suggestion by @CloudWanderer worked like a charm! Thanks for that. I still have that last question: Does the wild card affect any other certificate I might issue for another subdomain? or should I use wild cards every time I want to issue a certificate?

Comment: Glad to have helped!! Usually, whenever issuing SSL, it's good to include wildcard asking with main domain. If main domain has different SSL, new wildcard for subdomain should not impact it.

Comment: @CloudWanderer I see, thanks, so much! If you like, you can post your previous comment as answer, so I can accept it as such.

Comment: @axelrogg posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When issuing the ACM, did you also enter subdomain in the list? Also, its really helpful to issue wild card ACM for domain. eg -

1. main domain - mydomain.com
2. sub domain - my.subdomain.com
3. wild card - *.mydomain.com

With wild card you can map it to any sub domain.

Usually, whenever issuing SSL, it's good to include wildcard asking with main domain. If main domain has different SSL, new wildcard for subdomain should not impact it.